# Read and write ID's with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm new in Python and need help for following Problem:

I have two csv files, which named ***bib.csv*** and ***id.csv*** . The files have up to 15,000 Data inside.

***bib.csv*** looks like:

```
WKT  A_ID  length 
10   5     200
11   6     201
```

and ***id.csv*** looks like:

```
Master_ID  A_ID_1  A_ID_2
1          5       6
```

For two days I try to find a solution to write the Information of the ***bib.csv*** through the ***A_ID*** into the ***id.csv***

In the end I will have two csv files, where the ***length*** and ***WKT*** will stand instead of the ***A_ID*** in the ***id.csv***. 
For example:

```
Master_ID  A_ID_1  A_ID_2
1          200     201
```

and

```
Master_ID  A_ID_1  A_ID_2
1          10      11
```

I know to do this in Excel VBA, but I want to solve this Problem in Python.

I think my biggest problem is actually to know the correct search keywords to find Informationen.

With `df.loc` I find the values in the columns, but how to write this in the ***id.csv***???

Is it correct to loop through all rows and columns or is there a better way to find the ***A_ID***, ***WKT*** and ***length*** in the ***bib.csv***.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

bib = pd.DataFrame({'WKT':[10,11,12], 'A_ID':[5,6,7], 'length':[200,201,202]})
#    A_ID  WKT  length
# 0     5   10     200
# 1     6   11     201
# 2     7   12     202

ids = pd.DataFrame({'Master_ID':[1,2], 'A_ID_1':[5,5], 'A_ID_2':[6,7]})
#    A_ID_1  A_ID_2  Master_ID
# 0       5       6          1
# 1       5       7          2

melted = pd.melt(ids, id_vars='Master_ID', value_name='A_ID')
merged = pd.merge(melted, bib).drop('A_ID', axis=1)
result = merged.pivot(index='Master_ID', columns='variable')

print(result['WKT'])
print(result['length'])
```

yields

```
variable   A_ID_1  A_ID_2
Master_ID                
1              10      11
2              10      12


variable   A_ID_1  A_ID_2
Master_ID                
1             200     201
2             200     202
```

---

As [michael_j_ward points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951711/read-and-write-ids-with-pandas/37953608?noredirect=1#comment63355910_37953608), you can then use

```
result['WKT'].to_csv('WKT.csv')
result['length'].to_csv('length.csv')
```

to write the DataFrames to files as CSV.

---

When staring at `bib` and `ids` it's natural to want to somehow connect `bib['A_ID']` with `ids['A_ID_1']` and `ids['A_ID_2']`. `pd.merge` is the natural tool for merging columns from two DataFrames with common values.

But then we encounter the first stumbling block -- the `ids` DataFrame has the values in two columns. We want them in just one column. The solution to that problem is to use `pd.melt` to coalesce `A_ID_1` and `A_ID_2` into one column (called `A_ID`, below):

```
In [187]: melted = pd.melt(ids, id_vars='Master_ID', value_name='A_ID'); melted
Out[187]: 
   Master_ID variable  A_ID
0          1   A_ID_1     5
1          2   A_ID_1     5
2          1   A_ID_2     6
3          2   A_ID_2     7
```

Now we can merge `melted` with `bib`:

```
In [191]: merged = pd.merge(melted, bib).drop('A_ID', axis=1); merged
Out[191]: 
   Master_ID variable  WKT  length
0          1   A_ID_1   10     200
1          2   A_ID_1   10     200
2          1   A_ID_2   11     201
3          2   A_ID_2   12     202
```

and now pivoting produces:

```
In [189]: result = merged.pivot(index='Master_ID', columns='variable'); result
             WKT        length       
variable  A_ID_1 A_ID_2 A_ID_1 A_ID_2
Master_ID                            
1             10     11    200    201
2             10     12    200    202
```

Comment: And then `results['WKT'].to_csv("WKT.csv")` to actually create the csv files.

And once again @unutbu, an absolutely beautiful answer

Comment: Thats a great explanation! Thank you so much!!! I have not found the function .melted . before. Now I'm very happy.

Answer (score 0):

This could obviously use a some refactoring, but it accomplishes what you are trying to accomplish. The key is that you need a good map from rows in your `id.csv` file to rows in your desired output file. That is what `getBibMap` creates, then it's just a matter of iterating through and mapping.

```
import csv

def getBibMap(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as bib:
        bibreader = csv.reader(bib)
        next(bibreader) # ignore header
        bibmap = {A_ID: {"length": length, "WKT": WKT} for WKT, A_ID, length in bibreader} 
    return bibmap

bibmap = getBibMap("bib.csv")

with open("id.csv", "r") as ids:
    idReader = csv.reader(ids)
    headers = next(idReader)
    with open("lengths.csv", 'w') as lengths:
        lengthsWriter = csv.writer(lengths)
        lengthsWriter.writerow(headers)
        lengthsWriter.writerows((master_id, bibmap[id1]['length'], bibmap[id2]['length'])
                               for master_id, id1, id2 in idReader)

with open("id.csv", "r") as ids:
    idReader = csv.reader(ids)
    headers = next(idReader)
    with open("WKT.csv", 'w') as WKTs:
        wktWriter = csv.writer(WKTs)
        wktWriter.writerow(headers)
        wktWriter.writerows([master_id, bibmap[id1]['WKT'], bibmap[id2]['WKT']]
                               for master_id, id1, id2 in idReader)
```